outlook - how to search for specific time range
I would like to search macOS outlook for specific time range.  Does anyone know how to do that?
received:1/1/24..1/10/24 after:12:00 AM before:5:00 AM

I found this page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-in-the-new-outlook-for-mac-9c2e737e-050f-4125-addc-fa20fd03f291 but doesn't return any results.
Steps:

open outlook v16.83
go to inbox
in search bar enter received:1/1/24..1/20/24 or received:01/01/2024..01/20/2024

if you can't use outlook search is there a way to use spotlight?

Are you using the New Outlook? That guide is specific to the newest Outlook client, often called "New Outlook". Have you looked through the Advanced Search features, which can help you create a more specific query in a GUI.

@music2myear I did covert over to the new interface but don't think you can search time just date.

Yea, I am not aware of a way to specify Time in the search queries either.

Based on the article you provided, we can click search bar in New Outlook for Mac and choose the date range to search emails.

